# Show index page of domain1 when user enters the URL of domain2

Tags: domains, masking

I have two domains: www.domain1.com and www.domain2.com. I want to implement the following scenario:

Whenever a user enters www.domain2.com, the browser should display contents of www.domain1.com but the URL should remain www.domain2.com.

How can I implement this?

Comment: You need to add more detail. What's the underlying platform? Which technology stack do the two site use? More detail == better answer.

Comment: Hi Abbas,
www.domain2.com is just a domain purchased from goDaddy.com and web site is hosted in another domain that is domain1.com. The hosting provider is discountasp.net and written in Asp.Net.

Comment: www.domain2.com is just a domain and not a webhosting.. It is like I have registerd a domain but without any hosting plan.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using GoDaddy for domain2 you can take advantage of their masking solution for domain redirects. This allows the visitor to domain2 to visit domain1 while still seeing domain2 in the address bar.
The masking option is part of the redirect option within your GoDaddy domain control panel. More info can be found in the help files here: http://help.godaddy.com/article/422

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `CNAME` DNS record. So when users are on domain2.com they see content from domain1.com without using an `iframe` which isn't that good IMO

http://rscott.org/dns/cname.html

Comment: Of course, for this to work, the webserver at domain1.com must be [configured](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting) so that it accepts requests for pages on domain2.com and returns the same content as for domain1. But yes, as long as you take care of that, this is IMO the best solution.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen As long as you registered domain1.com and have control of it's DNS, same for domain2 there is no configuration on the server that need to be made to setup a CNAME other than name server and DNS control.

Comment: If your webhost is using name-based virtual hosting (which it most likely is, unless you run your own private server and have only one site running on it), it determines which content to send based on the original, unresolved hostname sent by the browser in the `Host` header. If the hostname it sees isn't anything it recognizes, it will show either an error message or some default page that is probably not what you want.

Comment: Read their question and comments they dont have hosting for domain2, it's pretty simple. User's go to domain2.com and see the content of domain1.com the most common way to do this is a `CNAME` record, they work just as well on shared hosting accounts.

Comment: Anagio: Why don't you try it? Set up a hostname on your own domain with a CNAME pointing to, say, webmasters.stackexchange.com, and see if you can get the content from this site to show up on your hostname. (Spoiler: it won't work.)

Comment: My previous comment `As long as you registered domain1.com and have control of it's DNS, same for domain2 `  I also have a CNAME on one of my domains support.mydomain.com pointing to mydomain.desk.com and guess what I don't own desk.com

Comment: What I'm trying to make you realize is that it also depends on the way the webserver at domain1 is configured. It _might_ work without any changes, if you're not using name-based virtual hosting. If you are, it won't. But you don't have to take my word for it, since I just did the experiment I suggested above: if you don't believe me, do a DNS lookup on `cnametest.vyznev.net` and then try to [visit it](http://cnametest.vyznev.net/).

Comment: I run an NGINX server on ec2 as well and can CNAME from it just fine. I think your server is just miss-configured if you can't setup a basic CNAME

Comment: I think you're a bit confused about something. [nginx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx) is a web server. A [CNAME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record) is a DNS record. Saying that you "can CNAME from an nginx server" is about as meaningful as saying that you have 100 GB Microsoft Linux CPU in your monitor.

Answer (score 0):

you can use iframe and put its src to your domain1.com and it width and height to 100% with no border.

> <IFRAME SRC="www.domain1.com" TITLE="Domain 1">
>
> </IFRAME>